# react-quill removing p and div tags from within the text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

When loading a text in the editor react-quill is removing the p and div tags from within the text. The ones in beginning and end of the text remains.

The text -

```
<div><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></div><div>Another paragraph.</div><div>Yet Another One.</div>
```

Shows up as -

```
<div><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>Another paragraph.Yet Another One.</div>
```